# textarea width not constrained by max-width when inside table

Tags: html, css, html-table

Hate to ask, as there's a bunch of seemingly related answers on SO already, but I can't find this exact combo.

I have a table containing a textarea, the textarea has a large cols attribute, but the textarea breaks its constraints even when max-width is applied.

Here is a working solution when the container is a div:
https://codepen.io/davewallace/pen/zwwRoN

```
.container {
    border:2px solid orange;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 10px; // added for clarity
}
.sub-container {
    padding: 10px; // added for clarity
    border:1px solid green;
}
textarea {
    max-width: 100%; // correctly constrained within the container's width
    border:1px dashed red;
}

<div class="container">
    <div class="sub-container">
        <textarea cols="80" rows="20" placeholder="Please don't outgrow the container!"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the same setup, but the container is instead a table (> tr > td):
https://codepen.io/davewallace/pen/EmmQNW

```
<div class="container">
    <table class="sub-container">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <textarea cols="80" rows="20" placeholder="Please don't outgrow the container!"></textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

.container {
    border:2px solid orange;
    width: 200px; // explicitly set to demonstrate, however I am actually using flexbox with a flex-basis value defined, with the same effect exhibited
    padding: 10px; // added for clarity
}
.sub-container {
    border: 1px solid green;
}
textarea {
    max-width: 100%; // should limit the default width provided by cols?
    margin: 10px; // added for clarity
    border:1px dashed red;
}
```

---

By specifying `width: 100%` as well as `max-width` on the table-constrained textarea, the constraints then are applied. I would like to avoid explicitly adding a width rule.

*So my question is, is there an elegant solution where I don't have to supply an explicit width rule, that will allow container width to be respected by the child textarea?*

Please note: I'm dealing with legacy code, so replacing the table is not a solution I can immediately consider.

Initially I was wondering if dropping the `cols` attribute from the textarea might suit, however that doesn't seem like the optimal solution and also would require me diving into legacy code that should not (yet) be touched.

Answer (score -1):

you know what `table-layout: fixed` is solution for you

```
<div class="container">
    <table class="sub-container">
        <tr>
            <td class="padding-10">
                <textarea  cols="" rows="20" placeholder="Please don't outgrow the container!"></textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

.container {
    border:2px solid orange;
    width: 200px; // explicitly set to demonstrate, however I am actually using flexbox with a flex-basis value defined, with the same effect exhibited
    padding: 10px; // added for clarity
}
.sub-container {
    border: 1px solid green;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
textarea {
    max-width: 100%; // should limit the default width provided by cols?
    margin: 0; // added for clarity
    border:1px dashed red;
    resize: vertical; // resize only vertical
    width: 96%; // width hack for ur solution
}
.padding-10{
    padding: 10px;
}
```

I have made certain changes in css and reset cols from textarea

updated codepen too https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rmmJvy

Comment: Noted, however I'd prefer not to have to delve into code outside of CSS for this - so the removal of `cols` is not ideal.

Comment: even if you keep your cols as is it should work, I have already tested this in my codepen, try it

Comment: You've also failed to note that I do not want to declare a width explicitly, "width hack for ur solution" - yeah, nah.